# How is it possible to call a function with parameters without passing in values? [Swift Playground]

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Swift Playground provided the following code. How's the speakText(graphic: )called without passing in parameters? (Obviously graphic is already placed in another segment of the code)

```
// Speak the text of graphic.
func speakText(graphic: Graphic) {
    speak(graphic.text)
}
func addGreeting(touch: Touch) {
    if touch.previousPlaceDistance < 60 { return }
    let greetings = ["howdy!", "hello", "hi", "ciao", "yo!", "hey!",       "what’s up?"]
    let greeting = greetings.randomItem
    let graphic = Graphic(text: greeting)
    graphic.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1)
    graphic.fontName = .chalkduster
    scene.place(graphic, at: touch.position)
    graphic.rotation = randomDouble(from: -30, to: 30)
}
// Create and add Speak tool.
let speakTool = Tool(name: "Speak", emojiIcon: "")
speakTool.onGraphicTouched = speakText(graphic: )
scene.tools.append(speakTool)
```

Answer (score 1):

`speakTool` is of type `Tool` which has a property `onGraphicTouched` that is of type `(Graphic) -> ()` which is a function/closure that takes a `Graphic` as input and returns nothing (`Void` or `()`).

`speakText(graphic:)` is a function pointer to your function defined above.  Note that that function has the required signature; it takes a `Graphic` and returns nothing.

So `speakTool.onGraphicTouched = speakText(graphic: )` assigns a pointer to the function to `onGraphicTouched` and when the graphic is touched, the `speakTool` will call `onGraphicTouched(someGraphic)` which will call `speakText(graphic: someGraphic)`.

You can read more about this in the section on *Function Types* in [Apple's Swift Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158)

Comment: Thx! Do you know a documentation or a reference where I can read more about this topic?

Comment: Check out the section on Function Types: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158