# Calling functions without parenthesis?? [Swift Playground]

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Swift provided the code below. How's it possible to call the squishEm function without parenthesis? Isn't that the syntax difference between a function and property?

```
func squishEm() {
// Iterate over graphics and squish each one.
for graphic in graphics {
    squishGraphic(graphic: graphic)
}
}

// Create and add Squish ’Em! button.
let squishButton = Button(name: "Squish ’Em!")
squishButton.onTap = squishEm
scene.button = squishButton
```

Comment: This is essentially the same question as your previous one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it possible to call a function with parameters without passing in values? \[Swift Playground\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851319/how-is-it-possible-to-call-a-function-with-parameters-without-passing-in-values)

Answer (score 8):

You are not invoking `squishEm`.  You are saying the `onTap` function for `squishButton` is the `squishEm` function.  When the button is tapped, internally it invokes `squishEm()`, using the parens.

A function invocation has parenthesis.
A reference to a function does not.

For further reading, I suggest reading the section "Function Types" in the [Swift documentation for Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).